# Dummy push technology?

Tags: android, server-push, http-streaming

I don't have any background on push technology and I need to learn how to make it work on Android as quickly as possible. Unfortunately, I also don't know how to make a push on the server-side. My background here is absolute 0. :|

- Do you know any services that provide a dummy push so that my application can connect to it and wait for the data?
- How about a dummy real time push technology like what is on those voice chat applications?
- Can you give me some links on how to implement push technology on Android in code?
- What keywords should I search on Google if I want to study push technology on Android? (I am referring to the required classes, etc.)

It would be nice if I could also learn how to create a push technology on the server side but right now, I badly need to learn how to receive a real time push (like streaming voice for voice chat) in Android first and I don't know any services online wherein I can connect my application to.

Comment: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html - Google API for achieving push notifications. There are other 3rd pardy ones around, if you search for something like 'Android push notifications' you should find them.

Comment: Thanks! I will look at it after I've read some of the materials I've found on the internet. Can I also use it to push live streams? Or is it really just for notifications only? How do I push a live stream?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

take a look to [Android Cloud to Device Messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/) and to nice tutorial by Lars Vogel about server and client implementation [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html).

Comment: Thanks, Simone! I'm already reading the link that you gave me. It was a good start for me. It says there that Android Cloud to Device Messaging is intended for notification only, not data transfer. But how about if I'm going to live stream something like when two or more people are having a voice chat? Is it still about push technology? If I understand the link you gave me correctly, I won't be able to continuously send the voice message via Googles C2DM servers? How do I implement something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3rd party solution like Urban Airship to handle server side push for both Android and iPhone.

[Urban Airship](http://urbanairship.com/products/push-notifications/)

Comment: Thanks! But is there any free API where I can push a live stream, not just notifications?